# Highlighting comments containing TODO in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, todo

Is there a way to tell Sublime to highlight comments that contain the word "TODO"?

I've looked for plugins that do this but haven't really been able to find much.

Comment: Sublime text puts a box around matches for the current selection, so you can just select the text TODO anywhere, and the rest will be highlighted.

Comment: This should be a default feature.

Answer (score 36):

[Sublime Linter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter) should do the trick. You can add underlining for custom static text.

All you need is the Sublime Package Manager:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search for "Package Control: Install Package"
3. Search for "SublimeLinter"

As stated by jon in the first comment:

> For ST3, the [SublimeLinter-annotations](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-annotations) plugin highlights TODO, FIXME etc.

Comment: For ST3, the [SublimeLinter-annotations](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-annotations) plugin highlights TODO, FIXME etc.

Comment: For ST2, do "Preferences" -> "Package Settings" -> "SublimeLinter" -> "Settings-default", set "sublimelinter_notes" to true

Comment: I cannot find out how to do this inside of Sublime Linter. I read through the settings and  through their readme page (I could not find more documentation on this plugin) I did not see any static highlighting in the current settings. Could you (or someone) show where this is done in this plugin?

Comment: I also installed SublimeLinter-annotations and that did just what I wanted and worked like a charm!  It did however require SublimeLinter as a prereq of course.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using the [TodoReview](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/TodoReview) plugin. It's very good and simple.

After installing it via Package Control, in order to use it on Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and type `TodoReview: Project Files`.

It will open up a tab with all TODOs in your project, where you can navigate with <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> and go to the TODOs location with <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: This didn't work for me. when I go to TodoReview: Project Files nothing happend, and I tried many combinations of writing TODO comments. I am on win8

Comment: @MladenJanjetović are u using sublime3? It works for me.

Comment: @@Fabricio - No, Sublime Text 2

Comment: @MladenJanjetović thats why then. Its for sub3

Comment: @Fabricio It doesn't work for me. I use sublime text3.

Comment: @damo not my fault lol. It works for me. Contact devs if u wish. I liked it a lot.

Comment: @Fabricio Sorry about that comment, but it working for me now :)

Comment: @MladenJanjetović it claims to work in ST2 also... Perhaps there's something else wrong? Did restarting ST help?

Comment: @MladenJanjetović another thought: did you include a colon in the TODO comment. eg: `#TODO : blah blah` - the regex used to find TODO's insists on the colon being present, possibly preceded by spaces. You can also change the regex to your liking..

Comment: @drevicko - restart is the first thing I tried and it didn't help. And when I wrote like you suggest, it just freeze the whole ST for the first time. And then again after few minutes it pop up with todo list :)

Comment: @drevicko removing the colon in the plugin's settings did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this plugin : https://github.com/robcowie/SublimeTODO
Maybe it can meet your requirement.

Comment: it searches for all TODO comments and displays them in a separate tab = nice, but it does not highlight them in the "edit" mode, like Vim does...

Answer (score 2):

The "highlight_code_remarks.py" plugin seems to do what you are looking for. It can be found on: https://bitbucket.org/theblacklion/sublime_plugins/src/

It requires some handwork to install, especially note that:

1. You don't just need to copy the highlight_code_remarks.py file, but also the entire "support" folder.
2. Read the Instructions on the beginning of highlight_code_remarks.py file. If you just want keyword highlighting, you may skip the part which explains how to install the key bindings.

In case of trouble also have a look at this forum post, that's where I originally found the plugin: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1745

---

...and just in case someone reading this has never installed a sublime plugin before: In Sublime Text, click "Preferences", then "Browse Packages..."

- Copy the files mentioned above belong to your "User" subfolder.
- The color scheme configuration files can be found in the "Color Scheme - Default" subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

Try the 
[HighlightWordsPlugin](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/todo-syntax-highlighting/27604/2). Worked great for me on Sublime Text 3

Comment: This plugin highlights background not words